# Erro em consulta única em banco Sqlite usando content provider

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, sqlite, uri, android-content-provider

Estou tendo um problema que ao tentar fazer uma consulta no banco de dados da minha aplicação por meio de Content Provider. Quando se inicia a tentativa de consulta ao banco de dados a aplicaçao quebra.Fiz testes utilizando um inteiro qualquer como id para a consulta, A aplicação funciona normalmente faz a busca no banco de dados e retorna que nao encontrou o valor no banco.Mas quando utilizo um id da forma que eu preciso nesse formato:3ade68b8gc0b0b0b3, A aplicação quebra.[image: Log do Erro quando a aplicação quebra.]

Comment: Utiliza nesse formato porquê? Se o ID é um inteiro e se o ContentProvider espera que o URI tenha um inteiro, tem de utilizar um inteiro.

Comment: o ID que uso é uma String que concateno formando a URI

Comment: fico preso a esse formato do id, pois estou trabalhando com uma api,e esse eh o identificador fornecido, preciso utilizar ele pra poder fazer comparações e buscas .Verificando se o ID que está sendo consultado na API já está no DB da minha aplicação

Comment: Se quer aceder o banco por esse valor o Content Provider tem de prover um método para esse efeito.

Comment: se faz isso no urimatcher?

Comment: Sim, tem de ter mais um `URI_MATCHER.addURI`, mas em vez de `#` use `*`. Terá de alterar pelo menos o método `query` para lidar com esse tipo de URI.

Comment: obrigado amigo , me ajudou a resolver.Estava tendo um problema no Loader tb, estava esquecendo de resetar ele.Ai nao renovava o id que estava pesquisando no DB.Você tem como me explicar a diferença quando utilizo o "#" ou quando utilizo "*".

Comment: O `#` indica ao URI_MATCHER que nesse local deve encontrar um inteiro, enquanto o `*` indica uma string.